# Trying to Insert data to multiple tables in single query in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im trying to add data to multiple tables using a single query. 
[image]
These two tables are contacts and address. I think the issue is with my address table. IS it a good idea to separate my address table? since multiple contacts can share the same address.(family)

**Query for inserting data**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (firstName,lastName,nickName,cellNumber,homeNumber,workNumber) VALUES ($firstName,$lastName,$nickName,$cellNumber,$homeNumber,$workNumber) "
        . "INSERT INTO address(street,city,state,country) VALUES($street,$city,$state,$country) INSERT INTO contacts (email,birthday,memo)"
        . "values($email,$birthday,$memo)";
```

**My HTML form**

```html
<fieldset>
                <legend>Register Form</legend>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                </div>
                 <div>
                    <input type="text" name="nickName" placeholder="Nick Name"/>
                </div>
                 <div>
                    <input type="text" name="cellNumber" placeholder="Cell Number"/>
                </div>
                 <div>
                    <input type="text" name="homeNumber" placeholder="Home Number"/>
                </div>
                 <div>
                    <input type="text" name="workNumber" placeholder="Work Number"/>
                </div>
                 <div>
                    <input type="text" name="street" placeholder="Street"/>
                </div>
                 <div>
                    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City"/>
                </div>
                 <div>
                    <input type="text" name="state" placeholder="state"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="country"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="birthday" placeholder="Birthday"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="small"></div>
                    <textarea name="memo" placeholder="Memo"></textarea>
                </div>    
                <input type="submit" name="addContact" value="Send"/>
            </fieldset>
```

Comment: You can't insert into multiple tables in one MySQL command. You could use transactions.

Comment: Can you not separate them with a `;`? So you do something like `INSERT INTO contacts (firstName,lastName,nickName,cellNumber,homeNumber,workNumber) VALUES ($firstName,$lastName,$nickName,$cellNumber,$homeNumber,$workNumber); INSERT INTO address(street,city,state,country) VALUES($street,$city,$state,$country); INSERT INTO contacts (email,birthday,memo) values($email,$birthday,$memo);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas i try your query u should modify and try this query:

Code :

```
      $sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (firstName,lastName,nickName,cellNumber,homeNumber,workNumber) VALUES ($firstName,$lastName,$nickName,$cellNumber,$homeNumber,$workNumber) " ; "INSERT INTO address(street,city,state,country) VALUES($street,$city,$state,$country)"; "INSERT INTO contacts (email,birthday,memo)
     values($email,$birthday,$memo)";
```

I think it should be must helpful.

Comment: Error: INSERT INTO contacts (firstName,lastName,nickName,cellNumber,homeNumber,workNumber) VALUES (Shelroy,Thomas,sdsds,6786765,6786765,6786765) 
Unknown column 'Shelroy' in 'field list'

Comment: please pass any string in values it always in single inverted comma like values('Shelroy','Thomas','sdsds',6786765,6786765,6786765) u should try this to insert query